# How can I import data from Outlook to Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

I am using Windows 7 and Outlook 2010. I am really annoyed with Microsoft, so I want to switch to Ubuntu (where Thunderbird is installed).

In Outlook I have my emails, some appointments and all contacts. I also have two archives (PST files) with mails.

Windows 7 is installed in `C:\` and my "Documents" drive is `D:\`. So when I switch to Ubuntu, the drive `D:\` will (hopefully) remain.

- How can I import my mails and my contacts from Outlook to Thunderbird (Linux)?
- Is it possible to import Filters from Outlook to Thunderbird?
- Is there a way to tell Thunderbird in Linux to store all data on the D: drive (I don't know if in Linux the drive will have an other name)?
- How can I import my mails from my PST files into Thunderbird on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thunderbird can automatically import emails etc. from Outlook using `Import` in the `Tools` menu -- however, that only works when you're running Thunderbird on Windows.

You could export and import the data manually, but it will probably be easier to install Thunderbird on Windows, used the automatic import and then copy your [profile folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Thunderbird) to your Thunderbird installation on Linux.

Make sure to check if Thunderbird has imported everything you need before you delete your windows installation, as I'm not quite sure if it will be able to import filters and appointments.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out. On the page I also found the following article: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_Manager There I see how to start the profile manager.

Comment: This does not work anymore with Thunderbird Version 38.1.0. See "Known Issues" section [here](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/38.1.0/releasenotes/).

Comment: When importing into a Thunderbird on Windows, it is important to make sure that the "bittyness" of Outlook and Thunderbird matches. Trying to import from a 32-bit Outlook into a 64-bit will result in a `Profile not found` error. See [this SO post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1440375/1118505).