# Import Outlook emails into Ubuntu. Solutions here don't work ('Profile not found')

Tags: thunderbird

I am trying to import my Outlook files from a Windows machine to another machine with just Ubuntu (22.04 LTS, GNOME VERSION 42.2) on it with Thunderbird.

This answer ([How to import outlook express mails into thunderbird mail client?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/271677/how-to-import-outlook-express-mails-into-thunderbird-mail-client)) doesn't work.

Thunderbird on my windows machine says

> No profile found

In a second approach, I used 3rd party software to convert my `.pst` file to `.mbox` and copied it to the Ubuntu machine. Thunderbird will not allow me to 'locate' the file for importing.
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You haven't provided any Ubuntu product/release details. They maybe helpful; and FYI: I had issues years ago too, but found it easy to import the PST file into `evolution` (GNOME's MUA) so used that instead.

Comment: It's the latest release of Ubuntu and Thunderbird.

Comment: Latest release; please be specific.  Latest release is Ubuntu Core 22 which was released in June 2022.  It's a server system and not usually used with *local* mail; it's a *headless* system.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS   GNOME VERSION 42.2

Comment: "*Thunderbird on my windows machine says 'No profile found'*" suggests that you cut corners and didn't bother to create a profile. That's an important step: Thunderbird on Ubuntu imports profiles, not orphaned mail folders.

Comment: I followed the install instructions to the letter.

Comment: It is important that the "bittyness" of Outlook and Thunderbird matches, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to import emails from Outlook into Thunderbird on my Windows machine and encountered the same error:

> No profile found

The solution for me was the following: As it turns out, I tried to import the emails from a 32-bit Outlook into a 64-bit Thunderbird. That does not work and triggers the above error message.

After uninstalling Thunderbird 64-bit and installing a 32-bit version instead, the import from Outlook worked like a charm.

You can then backup your email and restore it on your Ubuntu machine.